# How to update the database in Android Studio?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm creating an android application that helps prevent violence against women. I'm done creating the login and registration module. Now, I'm using voice recognition as an alarm and if it recognizes the word "help" the silent alarm will be triggered. I'm wondering how can I update the database once the user says "help". I want to store the word "help" in the database if the user says it. And also, I want to store his/her current location through GPS. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to store it in local db (sqlite) or you want to send the information to your server and store it in the database there?

Comment: I would like to send the information to my server. I already have my online database.

Comment: So you are not asking how to store the information in the database but how to send information to the server?

Comment: Actually, I want to store the updated information of the user including his/her current location whenever he/she says the word "help"

Comment: If the database updating is in the server so first you should connect your android client application to your server and send the information, and the fact that in the server you wiil insert it to a database is a different thing.
How your server application is implemented?

Comment: I'm only using a free hosting site. It holds my database and keeps it online everytime.